# Can you describe what this JavaScript function `parseField` does?

Tags: javascript

```
function parseField(field) {
  return field
    .split(/\[|\]/)
    .filter(function(s){ return s });
}
```

I use this to parse my form field.
And then use it like this:

```
var required = function(field){
  field = parseField(field);
  // do something
};
```

What does it do, and how does it work?

Comment: Welcome to the magic (and scary) world of regular expressions. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseField` takes a string, splits it into an list of all substrings between either left or right square brackets (`[` or `]`), and then returns all elements from that list that have at least one character (basically excluding the empty string, `""`).

- Splitting on the regular expression `/\[|\]/` is like saying "split on *both* `[` and `]`"
- `array.filter(s => s)` will return a new array omitting any elements that when coerced to a boolean give `false`. There are only a few values that will do this in JavaScript, and the only one of type string that exhibits this behavior is the empty string (`""`).

### Breakdown and Examples:

```js
function parseField (field) { // accept a string `field`
  return field
    .split(/\[|\]/) // splits `field` into an array of strings between each `[` or `]`
    .filter(function(s){ return s }) // keep each string only if it is truthy (not empty)
}

console.log(parseField('[stuff][thing]')) //=> ['stuff', 'thing']
console.log(parseField('[]')) //=> []
```

Comment: Thanks. Now that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It splits the variable you are parsing into the function where a value in `/\[|\]/` occurs, then taking each part that is split and populating them as separate elements within an array.

**Example**

You pass a value of `x[y/lol` into your function - it will return an array with values of `xylol`.

Comment: This is wrong and ignoring the fact that it's splitting on a regular expression thus it would only split on `[` or `]`

Comment: opening up a console and evaluating `"x[y/lol".split(/\[|\]/)` gives you `['x', 'y/lol']` actually.  the `/` character is not a delimiter in the regex provided to `split()`.